# PouchDB "db.get" is not resolving in Android api 28

Tags: pouchdb

The "db.get" function in PouchDb does not work on Android API 28 .

This is my function to get some information. However, neither the success nor the error logic is getting executed.

The code is working in iOS but not for android API 28 . No error is shown

```
getById : function(docId) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            db.get(docId).then(function(doc) {
               deferred.resolve(doc);
            }).catch(function(err){
                deferred.reject(err);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

Please let me know how resolve this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the platform you are using - I assume it is PWA or Cordova?

I have not seen JQuery defer() used before. The PouchDb documentation talks about using either callbacks or ES6 Promises so it might be wise to use those. With Promises your code would look more like this:

```
getById : function(docId) {
            return db.get(docId).then(function(doc) {
               return doc;
            }).catch(function(err){
                return err;
            });
        }
```

...this returns the resolved Promise, which requires the calling function to use "*.then(*". Hope this helps.